# ng-show not working inside ng-if section

Tags: angularjs

ng-show is not working in following code

```
<button ng-click="itemIndex=0;showHome=true;" class="btn btn-link">Home</button>

<div ng-if="itemIndex==0">
    <div ng-show="showHome">{{showHome}}
        <h3>Home Section</h3>
        <img ng-click="showHomeItems=showHomeItems?false:true;showHome=false;" ng-src="images/home.png"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="showHomeItems">
        Home Items{{showHome}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Without ng-if it is working fine but with ng-if its not working.

Comment: ng-if creates a child scope.  Try `$parent.showHome` or wrapping `showHome` in an object, so the reference can be passed to the child.

Comment: that helps thanks. @JamesBrierley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring a variable like this:

```
$scope.switch = {showHome : true}
```

and then use it in the html like this:

```
<div ng-show = "switch.showHome" >
```

Comment: Its working but could you explain me how it is different than $scope.showHome=true or $scope.showHome=false...other than beiing object?

Comment: @Ram Objects are a reference type.  When a child scope is created, it copies all the values of its parent scope.  If they are reference types, then both scopes will contain references to the same object, so either scope can make a change that the other cans see.  If they are primitive types (like booleans), then each scope will only see changes that it makes.

Comment: thats because two way data binding a single line answer, thats why we are using angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Read this [article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

There are some directives in Angular that create a child scope, like `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`.

Inside those scopes, the booleans (such as `showHome`) are searched only within that new scope, and not in the parent scope.

In order to avoid such bugs, it's considered best practice to place the logic in the controller (or service, just not in the HTML) inside an object, which is not a primitive variable and will be looked up in the scope prototypical chain.